Search Rest API not returning some content when using the {path} modifier
Background:
I've been building a document library search tool in PowerApps that uses a PowerAutomate flow to run the Search REST API. The whole ordeal has been trial and error because the documentation doesn't have great examples of syntax, which is why I've been using the [Sharepoint Search Query Tool]. This has helped me to iterate through my trials a lot faster.
Issue:
One of the last things I need to fix is: when I perform a search I can see every file in a specific folder. If I add a path restriction, some of the files do not display in the results.
Example:
Search text ='reusable', returns two files from folder "Parentpath/Useful/":[{Reusable_containers.sql},{reusable_containers.docx}]
BUT
Search text ='reusable (path:"Parentpath/Useful*")', returns only the word document from folder "Parentpath/Useful/": [{reusable_containers.docx}]
Is there something I'm missing, or is this just a current limitation?

When using Path in search queries in SharePoint Online, I always use the full url ie https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteurl/library/folder
If I'm trying to get files only, I generally also add
contentclass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary
IsDocument:true
